# how to use save session in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, gridview, linq-to-sql

```
public LECTURE_CLASS eklenenDers
{
    get { return (LECTURE_CLASS)Session["LECTURE_CLASS"]; }
}
```

How to show this session in gridview?

```
void grid(int kontrol)
{

    dbDataContext db = new dbDataContext();


    if (kontrol == 0)
    {


       grdDersProgrami.DataSource = eklenenDers;   //give a error             
        grdDersProgrami.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {
        //uyari
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of class is LECTURE_CLASS and what type of error you get?

Comment: "Invalid type of data source. IListSource ,IEnumerable or IDataSource should be. " give error.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a workaround for it. Maybe not the best, but should work.

```
if (kontrol == 0)
{
   List<LECTURE_CLASS> dataClasses = new List<LECTURE_CLASS>();
   dataClasses.Add(eklenenDers);
   grdDersProgrami.DataSource = dataClasses;             
   grdDersProgrami.DataBind();
}
```

That way your datasource is a `List<T>`, which is an allowed type for `GridView` Datasource.